# What are the objectives of Minecraft-Hexxit

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-technic-pack, minecraft-hexxit

I have been playing hexxit for a while now and I just keep raiding castles and ships and don't really seem to be getting anywhere, besides having like 5 stacks of diamonds (which may not even be all that useful).

What is the actual objective of Hexxit? Like what is it that I should be aiming to do or make and what are the end game items? I have tried searching a bit but can't really seem to find anything on it. Any help or ideas?

Comment: The *purpose* of Hexxit is to make it more like an RPG, and to add new content each update so there's always new things to do/explore/find. Don't know what the endgame content is (if any), but knowing the purpose may be useful perspective.

Comment: Hexxit actually contains very few mods, which are listed on their site (don't have the link right now). I'd suggest finding the "RPG"-type mods in the list, and reading their wikis or forum pages to see what kind of content they provide.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Yes, but majority of RPG's have end game items or objectives to actually complete. I can't seem to find anything :C.

Comment: I am now assuming, after some more research and playing, that any of the "hexxical" armours, such as scale armour, are the end game items as hexxical essence is hard to obtain and therefore the armour is hard to make. Just my guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hexxit adds three pages of achievements to what vanilla Minecraft has, full of adventuring and excitement. That gives you a kind of a map of its objectives.

Comment: Thankyou, I did not realise this at all surprisingly. This seems like the best answer!

Answer (score 2):

It's an adventure game, same as the original minecraft! You could always try to discover all the features of the modpack that you haven't known yet! I'm sure there are lots of interesting things you haven't crafted yet. There'd maybe be something new to try or discover. Still if you think you're already too well equipped and it gets boring then maybe you could try another modpack!

Comment: Yes, but I always thought these modpacks were intended to give you something to do and challenge players, rather than just stockpiling diamonds and building cool stuff. ie, Tekkit is about building machinery to make everything more productive and stuff and there are plenty of end game items to make.

Comment: @ReallyGoodPie Not really. Even in Tekkit, what do you do once you get the endgame items? Make more cool stuff... just like before. There is no end, not even the End is the end.

Comment: Yeah that's why it says 'The End **?** '

Answer (score 2):

I think that Hexxit doesn't have a clear goal. (Which is the same as Minecraft.)

Some goals you could set yourself:

- Make a full set of Hexxit gear
- Defeat all the bosses
- Defeat the hydra (the hardest Twilight Forest boss)
- Clear 50 dungeons
- Make a wall of every trophy from each epic moment you've ever had in Hexxit
- DO ALL OF THE ABOVE

Comment: I had already done those within the first 2 days of playing hexxit.  And maybe it was the scale armour, but Hydra seemed pretty easy. I just stayed under its belly and kept attacking ^_^

Answer (score 1):

A good thing to do is to go on a server with factions and make like a village and decorate it and stuff. Then try and get as many people to join as possible and give them quests to do to get promoted while you can sit back and relax. just show off to everyone how good you are and you can make like an arena so you can fight people and stuff. You can make buildings for each thing, bakery, blacksmith, trophy building and a townhall ect. If you've done that and killed all the bosses, raided each type of dungeon/tower, got every type of chocobo then you have finished the game

Comment: And if you're not on a server? I don't believe the original question is about playing on a server, but the goal in general.

Answer (score 1):

Things to do:

- Defeat all of the Twilight Forest bosses
- Make scale, hexxit and thief armour
- Make cloud and whirlwind boots
- Defeat normal bosses, e.g. Wither, Enderdragon
- Make a starbeam block
- Make frezorite, kreknorite and meteorite armour
- Beat new structures, e.g. pirate ship, pirate cove, volcano, castles, under ground bases
- Make the best Tinker's Construct tools

Answer (score 0):

There isn`t a real goal sorry but you seriously could play over LAN with friends to battle it out in a hunger game style arena, of your choice, course

Answer (score -1):

Honestly, the way I enjoy Hexxit most is by chilling with some friends and doing some stupid stuff. It's more fun with friends, let's be honest. Apart from that, the only real other thing to do is be insane. Take down bosses again - but this time using only a cactus dagger called "The Spiny Shank" and some classy armour and a monocle. Challenging yourself is the only real way to enjoy past the overpowered level. And because you have so many resources, dying won't be a problem, it'll just be a laugh.

That's better with friends. Seriously. Hexxit is better with friends.

Answer (score -2):

Try building an adventure map with a storyline useing the rpg mods

Comment: That's not really an *in-game* objective, which is what is (implicitly, but fairly obviously) being asked for.

Answer (score -3):

i have only played hexxit for about 1 and a half days now because i thought it was boring at first but what me and my friend did was if we got bored looked at 1. stuff in ***toomanyitems*** in recipe and see what we don't have or 2. look at stuff we don't know what to use for and see what to use for it (ex. what does essence make?) and we also move a lot once we have finished castles in the area and the other castles are far away.